# Is there a stotra for worship of Brahma?

Tags: brahma

In my horoscope the Atmakaraka is Brihaspati and the Amatyakaraka is Shani.
Brahma is Adhidevata for Brihaspati and Pratyabhidevata for Shani, therefore I think I could get great benefit from worship of Brahma.
Unfortunatelly I cannot find any stotra for Brahma.
Does someone know any?

Comment: Padmika I notice you ask a lot about NavaGrahas. It is good to worship them, but astrology is not the ONLY thing. I feel you are a bit bewildered by astrology and are kind of fearing that if you don't do astrology things, you may get problem. But trust me, no such thing is there. The NavaGrahas do affect us, but have more command of ourselves in our OWN hand. I myself have been tormented by these fears of astrology, this is why I want to tell you to stop fearing NavaGrahas and astrology.

Comment: Sometimes even big Yagyas do not solve problems, like Pandava did Rajasuya Yagya but still had to go to Vanavaas. And there are Asuras like Mahishasura who were very great and intelligent but wicked, yet Mahishasura who got Saayujya with Devi. So your life us in your command. You must trust your Ishta Devata , She/He is for your protection. Make your own life, instead of thinking that offering white flowers with raw milk to a Peepal Tree will pacify Moon et cetera stuff....

Comment: This bewilderment can give you stress fear anxiety OCD and delusional thoughts et cetera.., you will feel that only bad will happen if I do this good will happen... Nothing happens. I myself have gone through this excruciation, this is why I am concerned for you. Indeed, just once sit down and think about it. Today when I am fine, I have nothing left but regret. Trust yourself and your Ishta Devata. You have more command in your Hand.